# JQuery - Change Element's CSS When Hidden/Visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div toggle when an anchor is clicked. I'm trying to change an icon via class when the div is visible, and when it's hidden, but the code's not working.

Does anyone know how to do this?

```
// Toggle design/code
$(".design-n-code").click(function(e) {
    code.toggle();
}); code.hide();

// Handles the icon so users know it's active when code is visible.
if (code.is(':visible')) {
    $(this).addClass('code-active');
} else {
    $(this).removeClass('code-active');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for the visibility of the code should be in the handler. In the handler, `this` is referring to the clicked element, so you must call `addClass / removeClass` to the element `#icon-id` instead (adapt `#icon-id` to your proper id).

```
// Toggle design/code
$(".design-n-code").click(function(e) {
    code.toggle();

    // Handles the icon so users know it's active when code is visible.
    if (code.is(':visible')) {
      $('#icon-id').addClass('code-active');
    } else {
      $('#icon-id').removeClass('code-active');
    }
});
code.hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put the logic for checking the visiblity into the `click` handler. Otherwise, it will only execute once, and that is at the overall beginning of the script execution.

```
// Toggle design/code
$(".design-n-code").click(function() {
    code.toggle();

    // Handles the icon so users know it's active when code is visible.
    if (code.is(':visible')) {
      $(this).addClass('code-active');
    } else {
      $(this).removeClass('code-active');
    }
});
code.hide();
```

Comment: @Downvoter: please provide a comment explaining your reasoning.

Comment: Apologies, I was scrolling down to answer and clearly happened to tap on the down vote button.

Comment: @aztechy Haha, no problem. I edited my answer, so you can freely remove your downvote :D

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an anchor which when clicked, toggles another element, a div.  The use of 'this' when clicked won't change the other element's class then.

You would want something like this:

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="toggler">CLick me to toggle the other div</a> 
<div id="toBeToggled" class="IsShown">I have class abc</div>
```

JS

```
    $('#toggler').click(function() {
        var target = $('#toBeToggled');
        if (target.is(":visible")) {
            target.addClass('IsHidden').removeClass('IsShown');
            target.hide();
            // Demo purposes
            console.log(target.attr('class'));
        } else {
            target.addClass('IsShown').removeClass('IsHidden');
            target.show();
            // Demo purposes
            console.log(target.attr('class'));
        }
    });
```

[JS FIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aztechy/6sKaf/1/)